# PHP / Mustache : execute javascript from the mustache template

Tags: php, mustache, mustache.php

I'm trying to find the best way to use javascript with Mustache and PHP.

I have for example a mustache template:

```
<div>My html {{myvariable}}</div>
<script id="uniqueID"> 
 console.log('{{myvariable}}');
 // do something
</script>
```

My mustache templates are retrieved from an API, for example when I click on a button on a page. The API sends back a JSON to the client with the rendered mustache html template inside the JSON.

When doing this, the javascript is of course not executed.

If I add the javascript to the  and add the name of the script ID in an array to avoid adding the same script multiple times, it works. If this template needs to be executed multiple times on the page and the script is already in , the script will not be executed anymore.

It would work with eval() but I'm trying to avoid this as it goes against my CSP settings.

I need to have the JS included in the template because it needs to be populated with variables coming from PHP.

How could I solve this ?

Thanks

Comment: To be clear, you are only using mustache in PHP, not also in JS?

Comment: @ChrisHaas Yes, only in PHP. I'm only using JS to fetch the content from the API and insert in into my html.

Comment: Thanks. So, do you want to be able to return _any_ JavaScript from the server, and have the client run it? Per spec, `innerHTML` explicitly [does not execute](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#innerhtml0) any JavaScript added. There's [`setHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setHTML) with a Sanitizer, but I don't think anyone has implemented it. I think you need to define the specific JS you want to handle, and then explicitly return that in a dedicated section of your payload, and manually support each specific use-case.